# Fetch list of records with bookmark status

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have an app in which user can bookmark a post. To handle bookmarking, i have created a polymorphic model called `Bookmark`.

Now i need to display a list of all the posts (let's say 50 per page, paginated) with a title and bookmarked status for currently signed-in user.

I have two scenarios in my head how can i achieve this. And i don't like any of them.

1. Check bookmark status for each post when rendering a list - this produces N+1 query and is basically a horrible idea in general
2. Get a list of post IDs of a current page, fetch all the bookmarks for current user where `bookmarkable_id IN post_ids_of_current_page`, check which post is present on the bookmarkable list and display bookmarked status based on this.

This second is pretty reasonable but i would really like to merge it all into **one SQL query** (if possible, i'm not sure if that can be accomplished using `joins`). It's caused by the fact that, in fact, i'm not using it in regular rails views but in graphql API endpoint + SPA application and it's not that trivial to fetch the collection IDs and compare them. It just results in bigger amount of requests to the api which i would love to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out i can use `includes` method for this (which will produce two queries but it's still better than N+1). If anyone can share a one-query version with `joins`, i'll be more than happy to accept it's answer but, so far, i'm posting my solution which is enough for my needs.

```
class User
  has_many :bookmarks, as: :bookmarker
end

class Post
  has_many :bookmarks_as_bookmarkable, as: :bookmarkable, class_name: :Bookmark

  def bookmarked_by?(bookmarker)
    self.bookmarks_as_bookmarkable.to_a.select do |b|
      b.bookmarker_type == bookmarker.class.name &&
      b.bookmarker_id   == bookmarker.id
    end.any?
  end
end
```

And the results:

```
Post.includes(:bookmarks_as_bookmarkable).map { |p| u.bookmarked_by?(current_user) }`  
# SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts"
# SELECT "bookmarks".* FROM "bookmarks" WHERE "bookmarks"."bookmarkable_type" = ? AND "bookmarks"."bookmarkable_id" IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30)
#
# => [false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true]
```